# Python web scraping : urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

This is the first time I am trying to use Python for Web scraping. I have to extract some information from a website. I work in an institution, so I am using a proxy for Internet access.

I have used this code. Which works fine with URLs like e.g. https://www.google.co.in, or https://www.pythonprogramming.net

But when I use this URL: http://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=APOA1 which I need for scraping data, it shows

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Here is my code.

```
import urllib.request as req

proxy = req.ProxyHandler({'http': r'http://username:password@url:3128'})
auth = req.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = req.build_opener(proxy, auth, req.HTTPHandler)
req.install_opener(opener)
conn = req.urlopen('https://www.google.co.in')
return_str = conn.read()
print(return_str)
```

Please guide me on what the issue here which I am not able to understand.
Also while searching for the above error, I read something about absolute URLs. Is that related to it?

Comment: @LSerni Thanks a ton for correcting my language and grammar wherever it was needed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your proxy server, and your own host, seem to use two different DNS resolvers, or two resolvers updated at different instants in time.

So when you pass `www.genecards.org`, the proxy does not know that address, and the attempt to get address information (getAddrInfo) fails. Hence the error.

The problem is quite a bit more awkward than that, though. `GeneCards.org` is an alias for an Incapsula DNS host:

```
$ host www.genecards.org
www.genecards.org is an alias for 6hevx.x.incapdns.net.
```

And *that* machine **is itself a proxy**, hiding the real GeneCards site behind (so you *might* use `http://192.230.83.165/` as an address, *and it would never work*).

This kind of merry-go-round is used by those sites that, among other things - how shall I put it - *take a dim view of being scraped*:

[image: View of Incapsula Network]

So yes, you could try several things to make scraping work. **Chances are that they will only work for a short time, before being shut down harder and harder**. So in the best scenario, you would be forced to continuously update your scraping code. Which can, *and will*, break down whenever it's most inconvenient to you.

This is no accident: it is intentional on GeneCards' part, and clearly covered in their terms of service:

> Misuse of the Services
>
> 7.2 LifeMap may restrict, suspend or terminate the account of any Registered Users who abuses or misuses the GeneCards Suite Products. Misuse of the GeneCards Suite Products includes **scraping, spidering and/or crawling** GeneCards Suite Products; creating multiple or false profiles...

I suggest you take a different approach - try enquiring for a consultation license. Scraping a web site that does not care (or is unable, or hasn't yet come around) to providing its information in a easier format is one thing - *stealing* that information is quite different.

Also, note that you're connecting to a Squid proxy that in all probability is logging the username you're using. Any scraping made through that proxy would immediately be traced back to that user, in the event that LifeMap files a complaint for unauthorized scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping `url:3128` from your terminal. Provide responses? Problem seems related to security from server.

Comment: It is unlikely that `ping` will allow him to access a HTTP service with authentication. PING uses usually the ICMP protocol, while HTTP relies on TCP: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907734/1428679 .